# How to programmatically create editable wiki pages within the Pages library of an Enterprise Wiki site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I'm new to SharePoint. I'm trying to programmatically create a wiki page within the Pages library of an Enterprise Wiki site in SharePoint 2010. Here is my code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
        SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
        rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList wiki = rootWeb.Lists["Pages"];
        SPFolder rootFolder = wiki.RootFolder;
        SPFile wikiPage = rootFolder.Files.Add(String.Format("{0}/{1}", rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, "MyWikiPage.aspx"), SPTemplateFileType.WikiPage);
        SPListItem wikiItem = wikiPage.Item;
        wikiItem["PublishingPageContent"] = "my demo content";
        wikiItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

The page gets created but the problem is that the created page is not editable and the demo content is not inserted. When opened in edit mode, no content space is available and edit options are greyed out.

I have also tried setting the default content like this:

```
    wikiItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.WikiField] = "my demo content";
```

But that gives an invalid field error.

I have also tried creating the page with this line of code instead:

```
    SPFile wikiPage = SPUtility.CreateNewWikiPage(wiki, String.Format("{0}/{1}", rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, "MyWikiPage.aspx"));
```

But the result is exactly the same.

I have confirmed that "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature is turned on for the site and "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature is turned on for the site collection.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from my other thread on sharepoint.stackexchange.com, I came up with this solution:

Instead of targeting the Pages library with regular wiki manipulation routines, we need to create a new Publishing Page and update Content type properties accordingly.

For the benefit of others, here's the code that worked for me:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
    rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPList wiki = rootWeb.Lists["Pages"];
    String url = wiki.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
    PublishingSite pubSite = new PublishingSite(rootWeb.Site);
    string pageLayoutName = "EnterpriseWiki.aspx"; //Page Layout Name
    string layoutURL = rootWeb.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + pageLayoutName;
    PageLayout layout = pubSite.PageLayouts[layoutURL];
    PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(rootWeb);
    PublishingPage newWikiPage;
    string myWikiPage = "MyWikiPage.aspx"; //Page name
    newWikiPage = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(myWikiPage, layout);
    newWikiPage.Title = "My Wiki Page";
    newWikiPage.Update();
    rootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

Comment: [Don't dispose your `RootWeb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx)

Comment: hello,Were you able to add default content "My demo content" to your wiki page?

Answer (score 3):

### How to create wiki page using SSOM

**C#**

```
/// <summary>
/// Create Wiki Page
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wikiPages"></param>
/// <param name="pageName"></param>
/// <param name="pageContent"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static SPListItem CreateWikiPage(SPList wikiPages, string pageName, string pageContent)
{
   var web = wikiPages.ParentWeb;
   var pSite = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite(web.Site);
   var pageLayoutUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Site.Url,"/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx");
   var pageLayout = pSite.PageLayouts[pageLayoutUrl];
   var pWeb = Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
   var wikiPage = pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(pageName, pageLayout);
   var wikiItem = wikiPage.ListItem;
   wikiItem["PublishingPageContent"] = pageContent;
   wikiItem.Update();
   return wikiItem;
}
```

**PowerShell**

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

Function Create-WikiPage([string]$WebUrl,[string]$PageName,[string]$PageContent)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
    $wikiPages = $web.Lists["Pages"]
    $pSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($web.Site) 
    $pageLayoutUrl = $web.Site.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx"
    $pageLayout = $pSite.PageLayouts[$pageLayoutUrl]
    $pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $wikiPage = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add($PageName, $pageLayout);
    $wikiPage.Title = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PageName)
    $wikiItem = $wikiPage.ListItem
    $wikiItem["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent
    $wikiItem.Update()
}
```

Usage

```
Create-WikiPage -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.sp.dev/faq/" -PageName "FAQ.aspx" -PageContent "Welcome to FAQ"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I scoured the internet for how to do this in Graph Api, and I came up with nothing.  I wanted to post my method somewhere so the next poor soul won't have to figure it out on their own.

**How to create SharePoint Wiki Pages in Graph Api**

The problem here is that wiki pages are .aspx files in a site's drive and are also ListItems in the "Pages" list.  If you just try to create a List Item:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

const string TENANT_ID = "<YourTenantId>";
const string APP_ID = "<YourAppId>";
const string CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT = "<YourCertificateThumbprint>";
const string SITE_URL = "<YourSiteUrl>";

//Get certificate
X509Store certStore = new(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 cert = certStore.Certificates.First(cert => cert.Thumbprint == CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT);

//Get a client using your certificate
ClientCertificateCredential certCredential = new(TENANT_ID, APP_ID, cert);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(certCredential);

//Get the site by the url and get the "Pages" list in that site
Uri docSiteUrl = new(SITE_URL);
Site site = await graphClient.Sites[$"{docSiteUrl.Host}:{docSiteUrl.AbsolutePath}"].Request().GetAsync();
var pagesLists = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists.Request().Filter($"(displayName eq 'Pages')").Top(2).GetAsync();
List pagesList = pagesLists.Single();

//Try to add a new list item
ListItem itemToAdd = new()
{
    Fields = new()
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "PublishingPageContent", "<p>Hello, World!</p>" },
            { "PublishingPageLayout", "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page" }
        }
    }
};
var itemCreated = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[pagesList.Id].Items.Request().AddAsync(itemToAdd);
```

Then you'll get the following error:

> **Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException**: Files and folders should only be added to a DocumentLibrary via the OneDrive API

OK, so let's go ahead and create the item in the drive you'd say:

```
//Create a drive item
var drives = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
var pagesDrive = drives.Where(drv => drv.Name == "Pages").Single();
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<p>Hello, World!</p>"));
var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives[pagesDrive.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("hello.aspx").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

And hey presto, it worked!  Or, well, it ran.  Then you go to SharePoint and try to open it and you realize it's just a page.  It's not actually a Wiki Page.  No problem, let's just go ahead and change that page layout:

```
//Update the list item
var listItem = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives[pagesDrive.Id].Items[driveItem.Id].ListItem.Request().GetAsync();
FieldValueSet fieldstoUpdate = new()
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "PublishingPageContent", "<p>Hello, World!</p>" },
        { "PublishingPageLayout", "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page" }
    }
};
var updatedFields = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[pagesList.Id].Items[listItem.Id].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldstoUpdate);
```

But unfortunately we get:

> **Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException**: Field 'PublishingPageLayout' is read-only

So are we up a proverbial creek?  We can't create the list item directly, we can't edit the content type after it exists, and we can only upload the file name and contents to the drive endpoint.

The only way we could set the publishing properties is if somehow SharePoint were putting the publishing engine's metadata inside the document contents itself.  Let's just go ahead and manually create an empty wiki page, and download the file to see if there's any -OH MY GOD! LOOK AT ALL THAT METADATA!

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingIsFurlPage,SeoBrowserTitle,SeoMetaDescription,SeoKeywords,RobotsNoIndex,PublishingPageContent,AverageRating,RatingCount,Ratings,e1a5b98cdd71426dacb6e478c7a5882f,TaxCatchAllLabel,LikesCount,Suggested_x0020_Reading"><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">19</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingIsFurlPage msdt:dt="string">0</mso:PublishingIsFurlPage>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">Kubat, Luke</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
<mso:RobotsNoIndex msdt:dt="string">0</mso:RobotsNoIndex>
<mso:PublishingContactName msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactName>
<mso:PublishingPageLayoutName msdt:dt="string">EnterpriseWiki.aspx</mso:PublishingPageLayoutName>
<mso:Comments msdt:dt="string"></mso:Comments>
<mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">YOUR_SITE_HERE/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
<mso:TaskStatus msdt:dt="string">Not Started</mso:TaskStatus>
<mso:PublishingPageContent msdt:dt="string">&lt;p&gt;​​&#x21;&lt;/p&gt;</mso:PublishingPageContent>
<mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt="string">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
<title>Hello World</title></head>
```

Now, I won't pretend to be able to tell you what all of these fields do, and I'm guessing you can't use mine.  I've got some field on there I'm sure you don't have and vice versa.  But if you manually create a simple wiki page, download it as a template, replace the mso:PublishingPageContent contents with the XML-encoded page contents you want, then uploading like I did before will get you a valid Wiki Page:

```
//Create a drive item
string pageContents = @"<%@ Page Inherits=""Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=""~TemplatePageUrl"" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=""~masterurl/custom.master"" %><%@ Register Tagprefix=""SharePoint"" Namespace=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"" Assembly=""Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" %>
<html xmlns:mso=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" xmlns:msdt=""uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882""><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix=""mso:"" FieldList=""FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingIsFurlPage,SeoBrowserTitle,SeoMetaDescription,SeoKeywords,RobotsNoIndex,PublishingPageContent,AverageRating,RatingCount,Ratings,e1a5b98cdd71426dacb6e478c7a5882f,TaxCatchAllLabel,LikesCount,Suggested_x0020_Reading""><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt=""string"">19</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingIsFurlPage msdt:dt=""string"">0</mso:PublishingIsFurlPage>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt=""string"">Kubat, Luke</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt=""string""></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
<mso:RobotsNoIndex msdt:dt=""string"">0</mso:RobotsNoIndex>
<mso:PublishingContactName msdt:dt=""string""></mso:PublishingContactName>
<mso:PublishingPageLayoutName msdt:dt=""string"">EnterpriseWiki.aspx</mso:PublishingPageLayoutName>
<mso:Comments msdt:dt=""string""></mso:Comments>
<mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt=""string""></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt=""string"">YOUR_SITE_HERE/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
<mso:TaskStatus msdt:dt=""string"">Not Started</mso:TaskStatus>
<mso:PublishingPageContent msdt:dt=""string"">" + SecurityElement.Escape("<p>Hello, World!</p>") + @"</mso:PublishingPageContent>
<mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt=""string"">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
<title>Hello World</title></head>";

var drives = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
var pagesDrive = drives.Where(drv => drv.Name == "Pages").Single();
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageContents));
var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives[pagesDrive.Id].Root.ItemWithPath("hello.aspx").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

Again, you can't use my code here, you'll need to download your own.  And I'm using SecurityElement.Escape() to do my xml encoding of the wiki page contents I want.  But if you upload that file it should work.

What's even cooler is that once you have uploaded a valid file you can change the contents programmatically on the list item since it is only the template that's read only:

```
//Update the list item
var listItem = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives[pagesDrive.Id].Items[driveItem.Id].ListItem.Request().GetAsync();
FieldValueSet fieldstoUpdate = new()
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "PublishingPageContent", "<p>Hello, World!</p>" }
    }
};
var updatedFields = await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[pagesList.Id].Items[listItem.Id].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldstoUpdate);
```

That's just a bit easier than having to re-upload the whole template every time you want to edit.